# boolean indexing with loc returns NaN

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
numbers = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(numbers)
condition = df.loc[:, 1:2] < 4
df[condition]
```

```py
    0   1   2
0   NaN 2.0 3.0
1   NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN
```

Why am I getting these wrong results, and what can I do to get the correct results?

Answer (score 2):

Boolean condition has to be Series, but here your selected columns return `DataFrame`:

```
print (condition)
       1      2
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
```

So for convert boolean Dataframe to mask use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all `True`s per rows or
[`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) if at least one `True` per rows:

```
print (condition.any(axis=1))
print (condition.all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Or select only one column for condition:

```
print (df.loc[:, 1] < 4)
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool
```

---

```
print (df[condition.any(axis=1)])
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
```